# nmtui is not rendering correctly

Tags: networkmanager, character-encoding

When using `nmtui`, `â”Œ` and `â”`‚ are added in places where they definitely should not be (see attached screenshot):

[image: what nmtui currently looks like]

How can I solve this?

Comment: That looks like a terminal encoding issue - what terminal program are you using?

Comment: xfce terminal is being used

Comment: OK so try setting the encoding to UTF-8 - see for example [xfce4-terminal: 
Switching between different encodings](https://docs.xfce.org/apps/xfce4-terminal/usage#switching_between_different_encodings)

Comment: works, thx, twas the encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set encoding to UTF-8 from terminal>set encoding>default(utf8)